# Error On MongoDB Start Up

Tags: mongodb, macos, startup, osx-yosemite, database

When I run the `mongod` command on my Mac terminal, I receive the following errors/traces:

```
2015-06-23T11:16:36.387-0400 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] journal dir=/data/db/journal
2015-06-23T11:16:36.387-0400 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
2015-06-23T11:16:36.408-0400 I JOURNAL  [durability] Durability thread started
2015-06-23T11:16:36.408-0400 I JOURNAL  [journal writer] Journal writer thread started
2015-06-23T11:16:36.408-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=11867 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=6c4008a49528
2015-06-23T11:16:36.408-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.0.4
2015-06-23T11:16:36.408-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: nogitversion
2015-06-23T11:16:36.408-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build info: Darwin yosemitevm.local 14.3.0 Darwin Kernel Version 14.3.0: Mon Mar 23 11:59:05 PDT   2015; root:xnu-2782.20.48~5/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
2015-06-23T11:16:36.408-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: system
2015-06-23T11:16:36.408-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2015-06-23T11:16:36.408-0400 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] openExisting size 12288 less than minimum file size expectation /data/db/capone.0
2015-06-23T11:16:36.408-0400 I -        [initandlisten] Assertion failure false src/mongo/db/storage/mmap_v1/data_file.cpp 136
2015-06-23T11:16:36.411-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
0x109fc8baa 0x109f7542e 0x109f61a78 0x109d8350b 0x109db077f 0x109da59c3 0x109dae829 0x1099443b5 0x109823755 0x109821e13 0x109826f1c 0x7fff84f685c9 0x1
----- BEGIN BACKTRACE -----
{"backtrace":[{"b":"109821000","o":"7A7BAA"},{"b":"109821000","o":"75442E"},{"b":"109821000","o":"740A78"},{"b":"109821000","o":"56250B"},{"b":"109821000","o":"58F77F"},{"b":"109821000","o":"5849C3"},{"b":"109821000","o":"58D829"},{"b":"109821000","o":"1233B5"},{"b":"109821000","o":"2755"},{"b":"109821000","o":"E13"},{"b":"109821000","o":"5F1C"},{"b":"7FFF84F65000","o":"35C9"},{"b":"0","o":"1"}],"processInfo":{ "mongodbVersion" : "3.0.4", "gitVersion" : "nogitversion", "uname" : { "sysname" : "Darwin", "release" : "14.3.0", "version" : "Darwin Kernel Version 14.3.0: Mon Mar 23 11:59:05 PDT 2015; root:xnu-2782.20.48~5/RELEASE_X86_64", "machine" : "x86_64" }, "somap" : [ { "path" : "/usr/local/bin/mongod", "machType" : 2, "b" : "109821000", "buildId" : "7841AB5A3B193E7F98789A6E40F7C314" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFF85C79000", "buildId" : "CCEC13A5D0D931C5B0B01C564B4A20A6" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFF8A135000", "buildId" : "1B9530FD989B3174BB1CBDC159501710" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFF92E10000", "buildId" : "45E9A2E799C436B2BEE30C4E11614AD1" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFF913AE000", "buildId" : "D381EBC669D831D380845A80A32CB748" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFF89CBF000", "buildId" : "BF8FC133EE103DA69B9092039E28678F" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFF8DE96000", "buildId" : "0C68D3A6ACDD3EF3991ACC82C32AB836" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFF869EE000", "buildId" : "E178980139853949B7366B3378873301" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFF8B73B000", "buildId" : "502CF32B669B3709886208188225E4F0" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFF84F65000", "buildId" : "9EACCA38291D38CC811F7E9D1451E2D3" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFF8AA4A000", "buildId" : "77845842DE703CC5BD01C3D14227CED5" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFF84B79000", "buildId" : "FA89A113696E32718FE1A0D7324E8481" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFF8B88A000", "buildId" : "126CA2EDDE91308F8881B9DAEC3C63B6" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/system/libquarantine.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFF896D7000", "buildId" : "7AF900412768378A925AD83161863642" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFF87151000", "buildId" : "3485B5F46CE83C628DFD8736ED6E8531" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/system/libsystem_asl.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFF8713A000", "buildId" : "F153AC5B0542356E88C820A62CA704E2" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFF8FD27000", "buildId" : "9615D10AFCA73BE4AA1A1B195DACE1A1" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFF8FA17000", "buildId" : "86FBED7AF2C83591AD6F486DD57E6B6A" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/system/libsystem_configuration.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFF8C8A4000", "buildId" : "20F3B077179D3CB0A3C1C8602D53B4DB" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/system/libsystem_coreservices.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFF8D7B2000", "buildId" : "41B7C5785A5331C8A96FC73E030B0938" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/system/libsystem_coretls.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFF93323000", "buildId" : "6084A531252339F8B030811FA1A32FB5" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFF8C91C000", "buildId" : "62B70ECAE40D3C63896E7F00EC386DDB" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFF868F2000", "buildId" : "AEB3FE62476330508352D6F9AF961AE6" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFF93339000", "buildId" : "EAFD7BD00C303E7D9528F9916BA0167C" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFF8D3EC000", "buildId" : "1E12AB456D9636D0A226F24D9FB0D9D6" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFF91CC7000", "buildId" : "19BCC25757173502A71F95D65AFA861B" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFF8A18A000", "buildId" : "589A5F67BE2A3245A1810ECC9B53EB00" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/system/libsystem_networkextension.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFF8D346000", "buildId" : "29AB225BD7FB30ED960065D44B9A9442" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFF838B6000", "buildId" : "61147800F3203DAA850CBADF33855F29" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFF8D248000", "buildId" : "64E34079D7123D669CE2418624A5C040" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFF8AA4B000", "buildId" : "3103AA7F3BAE3673964947FFD7E15C97" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFF896C5000", "buildId" : "4CF771286BE03958B646707FA9CE61B2" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/system/libsystem_secinit.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFF8F84D000", "buildId" : "581DAD0F6B633A48B63B917AF799ABAA" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/system/libsystem_stats.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFF90658000", "buildId" : "FBC3F80FA0FB3BD69A7E800DE45F092E" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFF8D7B5000", "buildId" : "840F5301B55A307890B9FEFFD6CD741A" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/system/libunc.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFF89DAE000", "buildId" : "5676F7EAC1DF329FB006D2C3022B7D70" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFF8F806000", "buildId" : "BE7E51A0B6EA3A549CCA9D88F683A6D6" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFF8388D000", "buildId" : "D35D0DB2D7BD3BE48378062BFE545E1D" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFF8FAEF000", "buildId" : "759E155DBC423D4E869B6F57D477177C" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/libauto.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFF87434000", "buildId" : "A260789BD4D8316A9490254767B8A5F1" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFF8C8F0000", "buildId" : "88A22A0F87C63002BFBAAC0F2808B8B9" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/libDiagnosticMessagesClient.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFF83B09000", "buildId" : "2EE8E4365CDC34C599595BA218D507FB" } ] }}
mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEE+0x3A) [0x109fc8baa]
mongod(_ZN5mongo10logContextEPKc+0x10E) [0x109f7542e]
mongod(_ZN5mongo12verifyFailedEPKcS1_j+0x1D8) [0x109f61a78]
mongod(_ZN5mongo8DataFile12openExistingEPKc+0x46B) [0x109d8350b]
mongod(_ZN5mongo19MmapV1ExtentManager4initEPNS_16OperationContextE+0x13F) [0x109db077f]
mongod(_ZN5mongo26MMAPV1DatabaseCatalogEntryC2EPNS_16OperationContextERKNS_10StringDataES5_bb+0x163) [0x109da59c3]
mongod(_ZN5mongo12MMAPV1Engine23getDatabaseCatalogEntryEPNS_16OperationContextERKNS_10StringDataE+0x1C9) [0x109dae829] mongod(_ZN5mongo14DatabaseHolder6openDbEPNS_16OperationContextERKNS_10StringDataEPb+0xF5) [0x1099443b5]
mongod(_ZN5mongoL14_initAndListenEi+0x1455) [0x109823755]
mongod(_ZN5mongo13initAndListenEi+0x13) [0x109821e13]
mongod(main+0x3FC) [0x109826f1c]
libdyld.dylib(start+0x1) [0x7fff84f685c9]
??? [0x1]
-----  END BACKTRACE  -----
2015-06-23T11:16:36.412-0400 W STORAGE  [initandlisten] database /data/db <DB_NAME> could not be opened due to DBException 0: assertion src/mongo/db/storage/mmap_v1/data_file.cpp:136
2015-06-23T11:16:36.412-0400 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 0 assertion src/mongo/db/storage/mmap_v1/data_file.cpp:136, terminating
2015-06-23T11:16:36.412-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2015-06-23T11:16:36.412-0400 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2015-06-23T11:16:36.412-0400 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] removing socket file: /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
2015-06-23T11:16:36.412-0400 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2015-06-23T11:16:36.412-0400 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
2015-06-23T11:16:36.412-0400 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
2015-06-23T11:16:36.412-0400 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
2015-06-23T11:16:36.412-0400 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] journalCleanup...
2015-06-23T11:16:36.415-0400 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] removeJournalFiles
2015-06-23T11:16:36.415-0400 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] Terminating durability thread ...
2015-06-23T11:16:36.521-0400 I JOURNAL  [journal writer] Journal writer thread stopped
2015-06-23T11:16:36.521-0400 I JOURNAL  [durability] Durability thread stopped
2015-06-23T11:16:36.521-0400 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
2015-06-23T11:16:36.521-0400 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
2015-06-23T11:16:36.521-0400 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
2015-06-23T11:16:36.521-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 100
```

I have attempted to purge the files in my `/db/data` folder but to no avail. Does anyone have any suggestions for this issue I am seeing?

Answer (score 7):

Removing only **.ns** files might not work. I had to remove the **local.0** which was corrupted after a unforeseen restart of my machine. I have MongoDB 3.0.5

Comment: I had the same issue, and it seemed to me I had .ns and .0 files from old collections which were dropped. Removing these files allowed me to start mongo again.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing any old or corrupted .ns files in /data/db and then restart mongodb

Answer (score 0):

Before deleting any files, try to repair the database upon startup:

```
mongod --repair
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/repairDatabase/